# Facebook Realtime API and Access Token persistance

Tags: java, php, facebook, security, facebook-graph-api

I have an webapp which has a facebook log in and once a user logs in I store the user's access token in my db. I also have subscribed for user feed using realtime api. So when ever user adds a status or comments I would get callback from fb. This would just tell me that there is a change(I don't get the id of the comment or status). So I have to query the graph api with the stored access token to get the feed and see what are the things that are updated. So if I see that there is a new comment after the last query I had made, I would process it.

- Is there any way to get the id of the comment or status that was made
  by the user?

And I the access token that I get expires in an hour. So I can't query for data when there is a user update callback after an hour. I also can't ask the user to go to my app again and re authorize, since he won't use that app after log in(I just need him to log in to my webapp so that I can get his access token).

- Is there any way to get the access token without the user having to
  go through the authorization phase again(This is because user won't
  come to my app again after he logs in, we just poll for his fb
  activities)?

Thanks

Comment: You can extend your user access token expiration up to 2 months as documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/